# How do you make components of JPanel as a node in JTree usable?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treecellrenderer

When I click on the JButton nothing happens. This applies even for a JScrollPane that I put in (it shows, but will not scroll). Why is the JPanel not at the front? I get the sense that something has to be overridden. Should it be the expansion of the part that is not the arrow? If so, how is that done?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class test {

public test() {

    JTree tree = createTree();
    tree.setToggleClickCount(0);
    tree.setRowHeight(50);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));

    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setLocation(200, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

private JTree createTree() {
    int children = 4;
    int grandChildren = 3;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
    for (int j = 0; j < children; j++) {
        node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        root.add(node);
        for (int k = 0; k < grandChildren; k++)
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode());
    }
    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    return new JTree(model);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new test();
}
}

class PanelRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
JPanel panel;

public PanelRenderer() {
    panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
}

public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
        boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

    panel.add(new JLabel("aloha"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    JButton fg = new JButton("fg");
    panel.add(fg, BorderLayout.EAST);
    fg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    });
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 500));
    return panel;
}
}
```

This is for MadProgrammer who says that Renderers and Editors make an image of what you put down. In this example, the JButtons are clickable.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test extends JFrame {

public test() {
    super("TreeDemo");
    setSize(500, 500);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton theParent = new JButton("Feature Set #1");
    JButton thefeature = new JButton("sdfdsfds");
    JButton feature2 = new JButton("Second Feature");
    JButton feature3 = new JButton("Third Feature");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(theParent, true);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode n1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(thefeature, true);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode n2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(feature2, true);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode n3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(feature3, false);

    n1.add(n3);
    top.add(n1);
    top.add(n2);
    JTree tree = new JTree(top);
    p.add(tree, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(p);
    TestRenderer tr = new TestRenderer();
    TestEditor1 te = new TestEditor1();

    tree.setEditable(true);
    tree.setCellRenderer(tr);
    tree.setCellEditor(te);
}

public class TestEditor1 implements TreeCellEditor {

    public TestEditor1() {
    }

    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    public void cancelCellEditing() {
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt) {
        if (evt instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent mevt = (MouseEvent) evt;

            if (mevt.getClickCount() == 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return false;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode temp = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
        JComponent temp2 = (JComponent) temp.getUserObject();
        return temp2;

    }
}

public class TestRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    transient protected Icon closedIcon;
    transient protected Icon openIcon;

    public TestRenderer() {
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode temp = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
        JComponent temp2 = (JComponent) temp.getUserObject();
        temp2.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground"));

        return temp2;
    }

    public void setClosedIcon(Icon newIcon) {
        closedIcon = newIcon;
    }

    public void setOpenIcon(Icon newIcon) {
        openIcon = newIcon;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
JFrame frame = new test();
     frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
 {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
{
            System.exit(0);
       }
 });  

frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).  A renderer is nothing more then just a "image" of the component painted directly onto another component, it is not a "live" component

Comment: A renderer is a "rubber stamp" and editor is a live component, which can interact with the user...(expect you're not fulfilling the contract of the `TreeCellEditor`)

Comment: Wait, then why does this work? Please see the addition I've added to the post. Is it because the JButtons are initialized outside the renderer?

Comment: DON'T place components in the model.  In stead, let the renderer/editor make the decisions about how the should be rendered

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

A renderer is simply a "rubber stamp" which is used to "stamp" the view of the data that the component is renderering, it's not a life component.  Each cell in the view is rendered using the same instance of the renderering.

A editor on the other hand is a live component, which can respond to user interaction.  A view only has one active editor at a time.

You models should never carry components, they should simply carry state information you need in order to render (and edit) it.

[image: TreeEditor]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;

public class Test {

    public Test() {

        JTree tree = createTree();
        tree.setToggleClickCount(0);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new StateRenderer());
        tree.setCellEditor(new StateEditor());
        tree.setEditable(true);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(tree));

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTree createTree() {
        int children = 4;
        int grandChildren = 2;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new State("Films", false));
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node;

        String[] cat = {"Sci-Fi", "Fantasy", "Action", "Comedy"};
        String[][] films = {
            {"Star Wars", "Star Trek"},
            {"Lord of the Rings", "Conan"},
            {"Terminator", "Transformers"},
            {"Cheaper by the Doze", "Father of the Bride"}
        };
        for (int j = 0; j < children; j++) {
            node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new State(cat[j], false));
            root.add(node);
            for (int k = 0; k < grandChildren; k++) {
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new State(films[j][k], false)));
            }
        }
        DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        return new JTree(model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public class State {

        private String text;
        private boolean selected;

        public State(String text, boolean selected) {
            this.text = text;
            this.selected = selected;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

    }

    public class StateEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

        //JPanel panel;
        private JCheckBox checkBox;

        private State editorValue;

        public StateEditor() {
            checkBox = new JCheckBox();
            checkBox.setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            editorValue.setSelected(checkBox.isSelected());
            return editorValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

            System.out.println("...");

            if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
                State state = (State) node.getUserObject();
                editorValue = state;
                checkBox.setText(state.getText());
                checkBox.setSelected(state.isSelected());
            } else {
                checkBox.setText("??");
                checkBox.setSelected(false);
            }

            return checkBox;

        }

    }

    public class StateRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private JCheckBox checkBox;

        public StateRenderer() {
            checkBox = new JCheckBox();
            checkBox.setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
                        boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
                State state = (State) node.getUserObject();
                checkBox.setText(state.getText());
                checkBox.setSelected(state.isSelected());
            } else {
                checkBox.setText("??");
                checkBox.setSelected(false);
            }

            if (selected) {
                checkBox.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground"));
                checkBox.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground"));
            } else {
                checkBox.setForeground(tree.getForeground());
            }

            checkBox.setOpaque(selected);

            return checkBox;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This days we can clearly say that this statement makes no sense. Components theyselves are the state that is needed to paint them, which is done by UI peers then.

Comment: Which statement - if you follow the MVC principle, the model should never carry UI components - the views should be configured to present the model - it's not the models responsibility to dictate presentation

Comment: MVC is term from old smalltalk blue books, in Java awt/swing a component is itself a model for painting peer, and component's model is defacto an MVC over model adapter to your model, if you use treemodel directly it starts to dictate your data structures otherwise you need adapters, and it usually turns out that adapter is not M to M or V to V or C to C but mixed style MVC to MVC, thus taking in account a drawing framework you already have at least 3 MVC layers.